# Как получить href ссылки с использованием библиоетеки requests_html в python через cssSelectors?

Tags: python, парсер, requests, css-selectors, requests-html

Только учусь, прошу это учесть.
Вот с помощью xpath я могу получить значение href, а вот с помощью cssSelectors не получается.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

url = 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/'

s = HTMLSession()
response = s.get(url)
if response.status_code != 200:
    print (f'status_code {response.status_code}')
    exit()

links_xpath = response.html.xpath('//*[@class="s-post-summary--content-title"]/a/@href')

links_css_selectors = response.html.find('.s-post-summary--content-title > a') #?????

print(links_xpath[0], links_css_selectors[0] , sep = '\n-------------\n')
```

Буду признателен за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Тут проблема не с селектором, а с тем что он возвращает.
По документации [`.find()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/#requests_html.HTML.find) вернёт объект! Да, в общем то и [`.xpath()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/#requests_html.HTML.xpath) вернёт объект, но если как у Вас сделать с `@href`, то сразу вернёт ссылку.

Отвечая на вопрос, у css тоже есть такой селектор `::attr(href)`, но вот беда, с данной библиотекой он не работает, выдаст ошибку:

```
ExpressionError: Pseudo-elements are not supported.
```

Поэтому придётся использовать обходные пути, а именно работу с объектами.
Да поправят меня гуру, если всё же можно напрямую в селекторе выбрать с данной библиотекой.

По работе с объектом есть несколько вариантов:

1. выдаст искомую ссылку, которую ищем

```python
links_css_selectors[0].attrs['href']
```

2. Также выдаст relative-link, атрибут выдаёт `set`

```python
next(iter(links_css_selectors[0].links))
```

3. Опять получаем `set`, но ссылка будет полная вместе с базовым url.

```python
links_css_selectors[0].absolute_links
```

Чтобы код для обоих селекторов был одинаковый, можно в первом варианте с xpath также получать объект и пользоваться теми же методами.